# Django Rest Framework JWT: How to change token expiration message

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

When the JWT token that I'm sending is expired, I'm getting this message...

```
{
    "detail": "Signature has expired."
}
```

Now, I want to change the response with my custom message, like...

```
{
    "message": "token has expired.",
    "data": null,
    "status": 401
}
```

I tried it to do within APIView, but It's not working.

Comment: use django-rest-framework-simplejwt instead of django-rest-framework-jwt as it has been deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Here's what ive did for my project.
Not the best solution i guess. But it works fine.

1. create your own serializer.
2. Subclass your view from JSONWebTokenAPIView.
3. Then add whatever attrs you want to your response, customize response message etc in
   view code.

```
# serializer
class TokenSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    token = serializers.CharField()
```

```
# viewset
from rest_framework_jwt.utils import (
    jwt_decode_handler,
    jwt_get_username_from_payload_handler,
)

class VerifyLoginTokenAPIView(JSONWebTokenAPIView):
    serializer_class = TokenSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if not serializer.is_valid():
            return Response(
                {"success": False, "message": "token Invalid"},
                status=status.HTTP_406_NOT_ACCEPTABLE,
            )
        token = serializer.data.get("token")
        message = None
        try:
            payload = jwt_decode_handler(token)
        except Exception:
            payload = None
            message = "Invalid or expired token"  # --> Your customized response message
        if payload:
            username = jwt_get_username_from_payload_handler(payload)
            if username:
                try:
                    user = User.objects.get_by_natural_key(username)
                except User.DoesNotExist:
                    user = None
                else:
                    return Response(
                        {"success": True, "message": {"token": token, "user": user.id}},
                        status=status.HTTP_200_OK,
                    )
            message = "No User found"
        return Response(
            {"success": False, "message": message},
            status=status.HTTP_200_OK,
        )  # --> your customized response
```

Comment: problem is I'm sending token using header not body, request body also has data if it's POST and it's API specific. Do you any idea doing it with headers, like It'll check token before going to the API. I'm also ready to use any Abstract class to do that.

Comment: I have also an idea like "AllowAny" and check the token from the headers using a condition inside APIView. But It's lengthy & I've many API's to apply this process. :(

Comment: its for my project i've used AllowAny, you can use IsAuthenticated for your project. so that if user is authenticated then it'll proceed to api.
is this what you are looking for?